# Scala type mismatch error

Tags: generics, scala

I have a scenario that is causing a type mismatch that I cannot seem to resolve. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
abstract class Msg

trait Channel[M <: Msg] {
  def receive(): M
  def ack(envelope: M)
}

object ChannelSender {
  private var channel : Channel[_ <: Msg] = _
  def assignChannel(channel : Channel[_ <: Msg]) = this.channel = channel

  def test() {
    val msg = channel.receive()
    channel.ack(msg) // Type mismatch here
  }
}
```

The error from the compiler is:

> type mismatch; found : msg.type (with underlying type
>   com.msgtest.Envelope) required: _$1 where type _$1   <:
>   com.msgtest.Envelope

What sort of changes could I make to get this working? Additionally, the changes require that the following concrete implementation compile:

```
class SomeMsg extends Msg

object SomeChannel extends Channel[SomeMsg] {
  def receive(): SomeMsg = { null.asInstanceOf[SomeMsg] }
  def ack(envelope: SomeMsg) {}
}

object Setup {
  ChannelSender.assignChannel(SomeChannel)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could get it to compile under Scala 2.9 with two changes,

```
trait Channel[M <: Msg] {
  type M2 = M       // Introduce a type member that's externally visible
  def receive(): M2
  def ack(envelope: M2)
}

object ChannelSender {
  private var channel : Channel[_ <: Msg] = _
  def assignChannel(channel : Channel[_ <: Msg]) = this.channel = channel

  def test() {
    val c = channel  // An immutable value, so that c.M2 is stable
    val msg = c.receive()
    c.ack(msg)       // OK now
  }
}
```

The first change is to use an immutable value `val c = channel`, so that the path dependent type `c.M2` always means the same thing. The second change is to introduce a type member `type M2 = M` in trait `Channel`. I'm not totally sure why this is necessary (could it be a bug?). One thing to note is that `c.M2` is a valid type, whereas `c.M` is undefined.

Comment: Good stuff, thanks! I don't get why either of these changes were necessary though. If Channel.M isn't visible externally, then what good is it? Do we always have to create a type alias for type parameters to be usable outside of the trait/class? For the change to ChannelSender, wouldn't the path dependent type c.M2 mean the same thing since I'm calling `receive()` and `ack` on the same `channel` object?

Comment: Great questions. For the first one, I don't know the answer. Maybe someone more knowledgeable on the mailing list could help. For the second one, I agree that Scala could figure out that the `channel` object is unchanged in this case, but I assume that in general Scala makes the simplifying assumption that `var`s are untrusted to remain the same.